# Trace a line in an image MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am putting together a program to calculate some stuff with oscilloscope outputs, but as the program works now, I just import the image into MATLAB and then use ginput to find the coordinates of various regions on the generated curve.

Is there a way that I can take, say, this image:

[image: sine wave] (http://imgur.com/IlSDDLK) ![sine wave]

and have ginput or something similar automatically trace along the bright green curve and store the x,y coordinates to separate arrays (perhaps by being able to discriminate between the color of the curve and the background color)? That way I can instead use an actual plot of the x,y coordinates of the curve in the picture, instead of needing to actually use the image in the data analysis.

The closest I've been able to get is just using `[x,y]=ginput` to mash the mouse button along the curve and generate a massive array, but my fingers need rest!

Thanks!

Comment: One minor question, but very important:  Do the `x,y` coordinates of the generated curve need to correlate with the coordinate system of the oscilloscope?

Comment: Not really, just the x,y coordinates of the pixels where the points of the curve are located. It looks like the suggestion below might be exactly what I'm looking for - will update you guys once I manage to get to a computer.

Comment: Sounds good!  Was just curious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at this

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GH1x.jpg'); %// read the image
bw = img(:,:,2) > 128; %// pick only green points (2nd RGB channel)
bw(275:end,:) = false; %// discard the lower flat line
[yy xx]=find(bw); %// get the x-y coordinates of green pixels
```

Now you can plot the points:

```
figure;plot(xx,yy, '.');
```

Resulting with
[image]

If you are troubled by the fact that the line is thick (i.e., multiple y values for each x) you can simply take the mean

```
uy = accumarray( xx, yy, [], @mean );
ux = 1:max(xx);
```

Visualizing the line

```
figure;imshow( img );hold on; plot(ux,uy,'r','LineWidth',1.5);
```

[image]

---

If you are after the grid as well, then

```
[gy gx] = find( max(img,[],3) < 60); %// get the darkest points
```

To determine the grid points we seek `x` such that many grid points `gy` has the same `gx`

```
nx = hist(gx,1:size(img,2));  %// count how many gx per x location
gxx = find(nx > 100 ); %// only those with more than 100 are grid X
```

Same for y:

```
ny = hist(gy,1:334); 
gyy = find(ny > 100 );
```

Remove duplicates:

```
gxx( diff([0 gxx]) == 1 ) = [];
gyy( diff([0 gyy]) == 1 ) = [];
```

Create the grid points

```
[GX GY] = meshgrid(gxx, gyy);
```

Now the whole picture:

```
figure('Name','I MUST award Shai a FAT Bounty for this');
imshow( img );hold on;
plot(ux,uy,'r','LineWidth',1.5); %// the curve
scatter( GX(:), GY(:), 150, '+c'); %// the grid
```

[image]

Comment: Heh! Nothing like some simple thresholding to do the job. +1.

Comment: OK, now I see it with `accumarray`.  Excellent.

Comment: Would it be a similar process to also include the grid?

Comment: @bieberman you can get most of the grid points by `[gt gx] = find( max(img,[],3) < 60 );`

Comment: @Shai - I'd give you +10 if I could... your `title` is hilarious.

Comment: That's very nice stuff good job. And the name of the figure is indeed hilarious haha +1

Comment: @rayryeng I was hoping the title would be noticed only once the figure is actually displayed... ;)

Comment: @Shai - If the OP doesn't give you a bounty, then I will!

Comment: @rayryeng I'm not sure he can. Anyhow, save your reps for something more worthy.

Comment: @Shai - Well... you gave me a bounty for an even less worthy answer lol.  But OK, if you wish :)

Comment: @rayryeng it was a masterpiece of minimalism: distilling years of studying and hours of programming into a single syllable!

Comment: @Shai - LOL. That made me laugh very loudly. Thank you :)

Comment: ...how do you I give you a bounty haha? This is literally exactly what I was asking for, wonderful solution. Thank you so much Shai.