# Extracting Data from a Plot in a png using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, extract

I'd like to extract the curves from a plot using Matlab. I would like to select the color of the curves I wish to extract, and then have their coordinates output. I realize that having this done for a relative graph is complicated, so all I need are the pixel locations. From there I can analyze what they correspond to. An example image is provided, where I'd like to take the red curves, and output their locations to a text file.

[image: Phonon Spectrum]

An extremely nice addition to this would be to 'curve fit' the extracted pixels. The extracted graph values will most likely come from +5 pixel width curves which your numeric data will have width. It would be ideal to average out this behaviour and thin the data.

[image: Data and Desired Data]

Red are the pixels on a curve, blue are the effective pixels to be extracted instead. I see this being done in two ways: A transformation on the image, then extract the values, or vice-versa. I'm not sure which would be better.

Comment: You realise they'll come out in scanline order? I mean all red pixels in top row of image, followed by all red pixels in second row, etc.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, in column order in MATLAB. Captain Morgan, looks like this graph works pretty well with `Img(:,:,1) & ~Img(:,:,2)`. Are all of your graphs going to be so nice and neat?

Comment: It's doable in Matlab, but if this is a one-time task, I'd suggest using a web app "WebPlotDigitizer", where you can do it manually with high degree of accuracy. The intersecting red lines would make your life far more complicated if you make it with Matlab.

Comment: @Mark That is fine. I do not care of the order, I just need the locations of all instances of a single color. @beaker Yes, most would be this neat. Maybe two or two other colors, but most will be `simple'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trace a line in an image MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642674/trace-a-line-in-an-image-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost the same solution as Mark Setchell, but now in Matlab.

```
I = imread('DoEvE.png');
% select the red pixels
Ired = I(:,:,1) == 255 & I(:,:,2) == 0 & I(:,:,3) == 0;
figure
imshow(Ired)
[x, y] = find(Ired); % extract the (x, y) coordinates of the red pixels
hold on
plot(y, x, 'b.'); % plot the result to validate
```

[image]

Comment: The next step to expand on this would be to transform these curves with 'width', into discrete data. Having every pixel of desired color is great, as a simple transformation would make it fit the graph values, but to be able to do a form of curve fitting for the data would be phenomenal.

Comment: You can try it yourself first and ask a new question if you encounter some problems.

Answer (score 1):

As nobody seems to be providing a Matlab method, I am providing a method based on **ImageMagick** that may work for you. It is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows for free.

The following command in the Terminal (Command Prompt on Windows) will take your image, turn off the transparency and fill with black all pixels that are not within 10% of `red`.

```
magick plot.png -alpha off -fuzz 10% -fill black +opaque red result.png
```

[image]

If we do that exact same thing again, but then convert the image to text like this:

```
magick plot.png -alpha off -fuzz 10% -fill black +opaque red txt:
```

we will get this:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 650,455,65535,srgb
0,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
1,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
2,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
3,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
4,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
5,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
6,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
7,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
8,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
...
...
99,138: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
100,138: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
101,138: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
102,138: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
103,138: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
```

If we do the same thing again, but this time parse the output looking for `#FF0000` (on Windows you would use `FINDSTR` instead of `awk`) and just print the first field up to the colon:

```
magick plot.png -alpha off -fuzz 10% -fill black +opaque red txt: | awk -F: '/#FF0000/{print $1}'


99,138
100,138
101,138
102,138
103,138
434,138
439,138
440,138
...
...
```

As you are using Matlab, you would need to shell out to **ImageMagick** something like this:

```
[result,output]=system("magick plot.png -alpha off -fuzz 10% -fill black +opaque red txt: | awk -F: '/#FF0000/{print $1}'");
```

You may need a caret (`^`) on Windows to escape the `%` sign. Or you could put all the command in a BATCH file and just call that to save typing if you do it often.

Comment: I like this. I could throw these commands arbitrarily in to an f90 as to have an exe do the job. Matlab, I'm not sure how I'd operate that using fortran. Thanks!

Comment: You could do that, but @m7913d's solution is much more elegant. I'm voting for his!